# What is the correct approach to keep"sidebar view " and "footer views" without changing while reload main views?

Tags: backbone-views, backbone-routing

In my Backbone app, I am making a web app, contains the navigation and the footer, with the appropriate click on navi bar, i am loading new content to the main view.

when my initial page loads i am showing the navi bar views, and redirecting to dashboard using:

```
var naviView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$("body"),
        initialize:function(){
            this.$el.find("nav").append(this.template); // showing navigation
            APP.router.navigate("#/dashBoard/"); // redirecting to show main dashboard view
        }
    });
```

It works fine, But my issue is, whenerver i refresh with new view(dashBoard view), the navigation bar goes off. without refresh all works fine, i can click on any of the link to navigate new router.

so, how to keep the navigation bar or footer bars, to available to all views, including refresh pages, with remembering the link which is clicked finally.

here is my router:

```
var appRouters = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes:{
            "":"loginPageProcess",
            "initiate/":"initiate",
            "dashBoard/":"dashBoard",
            "myTask/":"myTask",
            "repositories/":"repositories",
            "saved-searches/":"savedSearches",
            "favourites/":"favourites",
            "reports/":"reports",
            "preferences/":"preferences"
        },
        initialize:function(){
            this.spaceHold();           
        },
        initiate:function(){
            this.spaceHold();
            var x = new naviView();
        },
        loginPageProcess:function(){
            this.spaceHold();
            new loginView();
        },
        spaceHold:function(){
            $("div.contentwrapper").empty();
        },
        dashBoard:function(){
            this.spaceHold();
            new dBView();
        },
        myTask:function(){
                this.spaceHold();
                new myTaskView();
            }
});
```

Any one help me..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this question at here:[Need help understanding the basics of nested views in backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278312/need-help-understanding-the-basics-of-nested-views-in-backbone)

thanks for all..